# Ideas about designing a database based web app

Tags: codeigniter, web-applications, database-design, vs-web-application-project

I'm creating a web app for my client as a part of my schools final project.
It's a web app where users fill forms (surveys) and after forms are submitted, 
values are saved in the database.

There are three types of users: admins, moderators and viewers. Admin's can see the
overview of filled forms, moderators will fill these forms and they also can make edits
to them and get the overview of the forms they've filled. We haven't discussed about the rights of viewers
at this point.

I'm using CodeIgniter as a framework of my project since it comes pretty handy when it comes to database
manipulation and forms. What would be the best way to implement this kind of situation? There are apprx.
4-5 forms (surveys) each moderator will fill. After they've filled them, they only can make edits to that particular form.
So one user can fill each form only once.

I've designed that each of the forms needs one table. So if there is a form (survey) about IT equipment, I will create 
a table for IT equipment. User's id number will be saved in to the last column in the table, usually called "user_ID" where I can
make queries based on users and check if user is already filled the particular form.

What about controllers and models? I've thought I could only make one model for inserting and editing the form.
However, is it pretty much the only way to create a controller or method foreach form since there are different types
of form fields to validate based on the form user is actually filling. I've already created a controller for inserting and updating
the IT equipment form and both of these methods are pretty big when it comes to the amount of code, over 200 lines per method. 
So that would be a total amount of 2000 lines of code just for inserting and editing all the forms.

What'd you do and how you'd implement this if dealing with similiar kind of project?

Thanks in advance for all the ideas and point of views!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into this:

http://cibonfire.com/

It's a really good addon for codeigniter, that allows you to data oriented development.